# From Figma to Zeplin: How to make icon importable?

Tags: figma

I have mobile app design in .fig file. I opened it in Figma

[image]

Imported it to Zeplin. However, icon image is not importable:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to make image importable to Android Studio like this:

[image]

Question: How to make image importable after exporting from Figma to Zeplin?